# Android Studio keeps selecting an unusable API by default

Tags: android-studio

I'm running Android Studio 2.1.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. When installing I chose to download API 24 without thinking and now it gets selected every time I start a new project. Because umake provided Android Studio with JDK 1.7, the Design View always shows an error 'Android N requires JDK 8'.

I can get past this by unchecking 'Automatically Pick Best' and choosing a lower API, but now the Design View is blank. I have to edit the xml and remove the following line;

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_Behavior"
```

Now I can finally see the Activity I'm building in the Design View.

What I'm looking for is a way to stop Android Studio from always having 'Automatically Pick Best' checked and API 24 selected every time i start a new project. Is this possible? It's a pain to have to go through all those steps each time.

Comment: Is it acceptable to delete all AS user settings?

Comment: @Fabio Any which way that fixes it is fine. It'll a new install so not much custom settings

Comment: I can't try on my install, but there's a folder usually at home folder, called something like android studio but starting with a dot. Try closing AS, deleting that and reopening. If you lose the settings but the problem persists then I misunderstood the problem. Otherwise I'll write a proper answer later.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks. I'll try it tomorrow and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio installs API 24 by default there is no way around this when you first install (at least that's the way it is with my ubuntu distro - you cannot uncheck API 24 even when you choose to do custom installation settings). `sudo umake android`

After the install, and before I created a new project I clicked the cog to open 'Configure' which allowed me to open the SDK Manager. In here I was able to install API 23 Marshmallow and delete API 24 Android N.

Now when I create a new project API 23 is selected and the Design View works fine.